# How can I keep the account session logged in?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I open chrome and log in to roblox, when I run the nodejs file it does not load my session, I'm **not** logged into roblox and it's like it's incognito and I'm not logged into the site which I am when I open chrome normally.
Note: I'm not using headless mode

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com/home');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

So I did more research and I found out you can add a [userDataDir](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.6.1&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions) and give it a path

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', headless: false, userDataDir: "C:\\Users\\InsertUserNameHere\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com/home');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Yep, that's probably so there's a place to store cookies like the session cookie.